# Changing Role permissions for an active (in-use) ServiceAccount in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-serviceaccount, kubernetes-rbac, k8s-rolebinding

Suppose a simple RBAC setup in Kubernetes (assuming `default` namespace for simplicity):

- `ServiceAccount` + `Role` + `RoleBinding`
- The role has allows to `get` and `list` verbs for `pods` and `pods/log`
- a `Pod` using the above `ServiceAccount`
- the pod is running `curl` to get all pods in `default` in a loop

As all entities are created, the pod is able to get the pods successfully.

Now, I want to change the underlying `Role` in the cluster - for example, restrict it to another namespace, or just remove permissions for the `Pods` altogether. Note that I'm only changing the `Role` - no other entities are changed.

My expectation is that eventually *somehow* the pod would get the change, and won't be able to get the pods anymore.

In fact, the pod continues to chug alone like nothing changed. I do know that the Bearer Token is mounted in the pod in a well-known location.

My question is this: is it the question of a longer time-out (in other words, if I let the pod run for X minutes, the change will take effect), or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this behavior. I update the permission in the underlying `Role` tied up with a `serviceAccount` using a `RoleBinding`. I exec back into the same running `pod`, and perform the same operation using `curl` (to make it identical to yours) but I get a `"pods \"xxx\" is forbidden: User \"xxx\" cannot get resource \"pods/exec\" in API group` while before it worked fine.